# Elastic-beanstalk gzip Python & Django

Tags: python, django, apache, gzip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to enable **gzip** compression for `Python 2.7` & `Django 1.11` with `Apache 2.4.39` (`Amazon`).

I successfully enabled **gzip** compression when I created an `Elastic Beanstalk php 7.2` application.

I placed the `.htaccess` file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d` and called it `compression.conf`

I restarted `Apache`

```
$ sudo service httpd restart
```

My **test.html** page used local `js` and `css` files which were now compressed with **gzip**.

The file comes from the compression section of `html5` boilerplate.

However, I failed with `Elastic Beanstalk`, `Python 2.7` and `Django 1.11`.

I placed the file here `/etc/httpd/conf.d/compression.conf`
restarted Apache

The local `css` and `js` files are not compressed.

There are no relevant errors in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Any suggestions welcome.

=================================

both files in .ebextensions

from html5boilerplate .htaccess file

```
<----------------- start enable_mod_deflate.conf ------------------------->

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Compression                                                        |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
    #
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding
    # https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/pushing-beyond-gzipping/

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
    #
    # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype

    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                      "application/javascript" \
                                      "application/json" \
                                      "application/ld+json" \
                                      "application/manifest+json" \
                                      "application/rdf+xml" \
                                      "application/rss+xml" \
                                      "application/schema+json" \
                                      "application/geo+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                      "application/wasm" \
                                      "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                      "application/x-javascript" \
                                      "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                      "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                      "application/xml" \
                                      "font/eot" \
                                      "font/opentype" \
                                      "font/otf" \
                                      "image/bmp" \
                                      "image/svg+xml" \
                                      "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                      "text/cache-manifest" \
                                      "text/calendar" \
                                      "text/css" \
                                      "text/html" \
                                      "text/javascript" \
                                      "text/plain" \
                                      "text/markdown" \
                                      "text/vcard" \
                                      "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                      "text/vtt" \
                                      "text/x-component" \
                                      "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                      "text/xml"

    </IfModule>

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Map the following filename extensions to the specified
    # encoding type in order to make Apache serve the file types
    # with the appropriate `Content-Encoding` response header
    # (do note that this will NOT make Apache compress them!).
    #
    # If these files types would be served without an appropriate
    # `Content-Enable` response header, client applications (e.g.:
    # browsers) wouldn't know that they first need to uncompress
    # the response, and thus, wouldn't be able to understand the
    # content.
    #
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding
    # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addencoding

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip              svgz
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
 <--------------------------enable_mod_deflate.conf  ------------------------------>

<---------------------- myapp.config ------------------------------------->
 container_commands:
  01_setup_apache:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"

<---------------------- end myapp.config ------------------------------------->
```

Based on:
http://www.tonmoygoswami.com/2013/05/how-to-enable-gzip-on-amazon-elastic.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do that it would be create a file in your `.ebextensions` directory.
Use this folder to configure all files that will run every time your machine starts.
So, you don't need to access the machine and change the config manually.

Create a file `.ebextensions/gzip.config` like this:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml+rss
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/gif
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg

        DeflateCompressionLevel 9 # Highest level
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
          Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
        </IfModule>
      </IfModule>
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Have you tested this on Django 1.11 and Python 2.7?


errors:
Helloapp-env-2

[Instance: i-03905e92f051a489c] Command failed on instance. 

Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...apache_is_running() File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/config.py", line 280, in ensure_apache_is_running raise PythonHooksError("Apache is not running, but it's supposed to be.") config.PythonHooksError: Apache is not running, but it's supposed to be. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01flip.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console

Comment: @johnc Some people said that it was necessary a restart on Apache to work. I would suggest that you try deploying your .conf totally empty, just to check if the server starts ok and the file will be created or copied on `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` properly. Otherwise, you could have some mistake in your .conf content.

Comment: I tried again and got rid any errors. However, Apache did not gzip the files.  I now think this is because they are hosted on Amazon S3 <link type="text/css" href="https://standtall-design.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" /> and do not share the domain name.  I have worked around the problem by gziping the files using 7zip.  Once I added the metadata to each of the 5 files in S3 (Content-Encoding    gzip) it worked and the browser shows the compressed and uncompressed size in the network tab
Thanks for your help

Comment: Remember that if you need this for a json API rest, you have to add a line for that
`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json`